# Instantiate the Endofunctor type with the Show class

Tags: haskell

How can the `Show` class be instantiated with the `Endo` type?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Monoid

data Value
    = E (Endo [Value])
    | I Int
    deriving Show

instance Show (Endo [Value]) where
   show (Endo f) = ... -- f :: a -> a
```

I would like to be able to display the content of my constructor `E` and I know that wanting to display a function doesn't make much sense, so how do I view the content of my list, if possible, how do I do this correctly?

Comment: Wait, why aren't you just writing `instance Show Value` instead of deriving it and then trying to invent something for `Endo`? Don't just blindly accept compiler error recommendations. Think about them and fix the underlying problem instead.

Comment: @Carl I have already tried to do this, but GHC returns the following error: `No instance for (Show (Endo [Value]))`, which seems to be resolved with my instance (but there is a hole in my program, because I don't know the implementation for `Show (Endo [Value])`)

Comment: @RobinZigmond: sorry, I misread it :s

Comment: *What* do you want to display, exactly? Can you show an example?

Comment: There is no list to display inside a `Endo [Value]`. "how do I view the content of my list" -- you can't, since there is no list. At best, you can _provide_ a list (which has to be conjured from thin air, in some arbitrary way, e.g. `[]`), apply your endo to that, and then recursively print the resulting list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just write a `Show` instance for `Value`. One such instance would look roughly like this (untested) :

```
instance Show Value where
    Show (I i) = "I " ++ show i
    show (E (Endo e)) = "E (Endo (" ++ show (e []) ++ "++))"
```

Comment: how do we know though that it's not `(++ e [])`? it could even be weaving them together, conceivably? it could even not have any list "inside", i.e. a `[a] -> [a]` function could be e.g. skipping every second element in the argument, too.

Comment: `E (Endo reverse)` is one example, and it's sure isn't `E (Endo ([] ++))`. :) So I was too hasty with the upvote, sorry. :)

Comment: @WillNess true enough, but as I said.. It's *one example*.

Comment: aah, you mean if the prepending really was what the OP had in mind with their Endos there. OK. (still, it's too loose, on their part...)

Comment: Also, it's how Endo is used about 99% of the time. It's probably correct here. But the fact that there's no guarantee is why there's no general Show instance.